# Update HTML text based on backend respond

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I need to update html tag text, based on respond from backend. I am using Django server to run the app. In the backend, I am running a timer, measuring the amount of time, the process had taken. I need to get this amount of time to frontend, and display it.

```
class Timer():
    def __init__(self):
        self._start_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        print(self._start_time)

    def elapsed_time(self):
        return (datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0) - self._start_time).seconds
```

```
urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^$', views.output, name='output')
]
```

```
views.py:
def output(request):
    time = timer.elapsed_time()
    return time
```

```
And my html looks this so far:
<td class="value" id="elapsed-time">00:00</td>
<script>
    var urlMappings = {
         url_elapsed_time : "{% url 'output' %}"
      }
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: urlMappings.url_elapsed_time
      }).done(function(data){
          console.log("Done");
      }).fail(function(data){
         console.log("Fail");
      });
</script>
```

So far, I am only getting 403 error message. Any help?

Comment: 403 with ajax is often an issue with csrf, check this part of the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: If you're getting a 403 response then it means the server is denying you access. You need to determine why that is. Authentication required, perhaps?

Comment: What's the error you see in your django console? If you get 403 it means an error is raised in django and you should see a more detailled error trace.

Comment: I just get [10/Sep/2019 13:00:06]"POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 2274.

Comment: You can't have both home and output mapped to the same URL path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this process...

```
$.ajax('yourRrquestURL',{
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success:function () {
        console.log("Done");
    },
    error:function () {
        console.log("Fail");
    }
);
```

or

```
$.ajax('yourRrquestURL',{
    method: 'GET',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success:function () {
        console.log("Done");
    },
    error:function () {
        console.log("Fail");
    }
);
```